# Conjunction and preposition

Tags: conjunctions

> Never before in the history

The question I have is about the function of the word "before". Is it acting as a conjunction or a preposition?

If it is functioning as a preposition, then another question arises whether we can use one preposition after the other. Because "in" follows the word "before". 
Please provide a specific answer to this question.

Comment: What is the full sentence?

Comment: Neither. It's acting as a temporal adverb, meaning 'never before now'. It's better not to worry about what "part of speech" every word is; just listen to the way they're used.

Comment: Bill i couldn't find the passage .

Comment: Can we use "NEVER BEFORE IN" in a row

Comment: Questions not providing the full sentence should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, *before* is a preposition in this case. It is modifying adverb *never*, and the whole adverb phrase *never before in the history of...* is likely an adjunct of frequency in a sentence something like:

> Never before in the history of U.S. politics have the wives of two
>   presidential candidates squared off so directly

Notice that we could have:

> Never have the wives...
>
> Never before have the wives...
>
> Never before in the history of U.S. politics have the wives...

As far as prepositions taking prepositional phrase complements,

> The dog got out from under the bed.

is a pretty uncontroversial example of prepositions following one another in a sentence. Many more examples of similar constructions are out there.